# Can't connect to mysql using PHP on google cloud. No errors popup

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is my `main.php` code just to try connecting to MySQL database and check if it can connect to it or not.

```
<?php
$USER = "root";
$PASS = "";// I do have a password. I just haven't mentioned on StackOverflow
$IP  = "104.199.248.141";
$DB   = "Contacts";

$conn = mysqli_connect($IP,$USER,$PASS,$DB,null,"/cloudsql/adiscontactbook:asia-east1:contacts-book");
if($conn != null) {
    print("Connected! :*");
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    print("Can't connect! :(");
}
?>
```

And this is `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

I **CAN** connect to my mysql instance via terminal by typing:

```
mysql --host=104.199.248.141 --user=root --password
```

and the output on terminal is `Connected! :*`.

This is my app URL: `https://adiscontactbook.appspot.com/`

When I type the URL in the browser, it outputs `Can't connect! :(`.

PS: I have given permissions to my app and as well as my local computer in the `Authorize networks` section to access the mysql instance by entering the IP address `35.185.186.77`(external IP of my app) and `14.97.103.225` respectively.

Why is it so that I have no problem accessing it via terminal but can't connect via browser by typing the URL?

Comment: Instead of outputting 'can't connect' look what was the actual error: http://php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: @Danny i tried that. It doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass null to the `$host` parameter, as you're connecting through a socket.

```
$conn = mysqli(null, $USER, $PASS, $DB,null, "/cloudsql/adiscontactbook:asia-east1:contacts-book")
```

Comment: Hey! This actually worked. But I fail to understand why it worked. :D Will you please explain? I didn't enter the port number and socket before. Just ip address, username, password and DB name. Still it couldn't connect. Why does it connect now? Please elaborate.

Comment: Passing the `$host` parameter will cause the connection to use TCP/IP instead of socket. Google requires you to connect through socket.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth parameter of mysqli_connect is the port number and the sixth parameter is the socket path. You can try to leave out the fifth and sixth parameters. See the documentation for mysqli_connect (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Is your mysql server accessible over a TCP socket or a Unix Socket?

Comment: It must be. Coz I can connect to it via terminal. Using the "mysql" tool.

Comment: Try to use localhost or  127.0.0.1 for the host name

Comment: But VM has a different IP. And MYSQL has a different IP. They aren't on the same computers. How is it gonna work?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole day trying to figure this out....was converting from mysql to mysqli in preparation for php7 and 2nd generation CloudSQL from appengine.  I couldn't find anywhere in the doc that you had to use this 6 parameter format for the mysqli_connect() function.

In addition, the ":" that precedes the server name in the mysql_connect needs to be removed (but not the forward slash '/') when using it with mysqli.  Hence:

```
$servername=":/cloudsql/project:us-east1:database";
```

becomes:

```
$servername="/cloudsql/project:us-east1:database";
```